# Foobar playing too fast in linux wine (pulse audio alsa underrun error)

Tags: linux, audio, wine, pulse-audio, foobar2000

When running multiple apps under heavy cpu and file transfer load (like rsync), foobar starts playing very fast (like 10x speed).

Answer (score 0):

*It might seem long and complicated, but its actually just editing 2 lines of text.*

**Summary version:**

Open file

```
$ nano ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Edit/add these 2 lines to the below

```
default-fragments = 10
default-fragment-size-msec = 1000
```

Restart pulseaudio

```
$ pulseaudio --kill && systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket && systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service && sleep 2 && pulseaudio --start
```

Restart foobar. Done.

**Long Version:**

Troubleshooting:

Run it from the terminal to check for errors (edit the path to yours):

```
$ wine-development start /unix "/media/user/drive/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe"
```

Note:

1. wine-development is the bleeding edge version of wine. Install it if you want (it has solved some problems for me in the past).
2. I am running a portable foobar, thats why its not in the Program Files folder.

Now if you are seeing a error in the terminal like:

```
ALSA lib pcm.c:8526:(snd_pcm_recover) underrun occurred
```

**This can be solved.**
We just need to change/add 2 lines in daemon.conf.

Check in home directory if

```
~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

exists.

If not, copy it from etc

```
$ cp /etc/pulse/daemon.conf ~/.config/pulse/daemon.conf
```

Add/edit these 2 lines in daemon.conf

```
default-fragments = 10
default-fragment-size-msec = 1000
```

ie., 10 pieces of 1000ms audio is preprocessed by pulseaudio. This should solve even the heaviest load problem. Decrease it to the minimum required if you want. Increasing this is supposed to increase latency, but I have left it like this and not had any latency issues.

Now to restart pulse:

Check its process id first so that we can see if it actually restarted. Restarting pulse is sometimes problematic and you may need to restart the pc if the below fails.

```
$ ps cax | grep pulseaudio
```

output

```
967930 ?        S<l    0:00 pulseaudio
```

This number varies.

Now restart pulse

```
$ pulseaudio --kill && systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.socket && systemctl --user stop pulseaudio.service && sleep 2 && pulseaudio --start
```

Now check process id again

```
$ ps cax | grep pulseaudio
```

output

```
1008985 ?        S<l    0:00 pulseaudio
```

Has the number changed? If yes, then restart worked. If not, you have to do a pc restart.

Restart foobar (else it won't play)

```
$ kill -9 $(pgrep foobar2000) && wine-development start /unix "/media/user/drive/foobar2000/foobar2000.exe"
```

See if audio is playing smoothly (a few underrun errors are ok).

Note:

If you are running compression inside foobar while an audio is playing the above method may not work. In that case its better to have another foobar running simultaneously and do compression in one and listening in the other. This is because foobar/wine is not good at multithreading. Use foobar portable for this.